# How to add a custom popover event to show a menu in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, charts, highcharts

I understand that Highcharts itself does not provide a built-in menu pop-up functionality, but you can use any JavaScript or CSS library of your choice to implement it.

Does anyone have an example of implementing such a feature in Highcharts? I have tried on this fiddle but there is a script error

For the node 'Baptiste AG' I have included an event to pop a menu, but the script has an error.

`https://jsfiddle.net/Dom_Snell1/cqyb95nx/2/`

`link to jsfiddle`

I tried adding in jquery and bootsrap libraries and then adding in a function to pop the menu.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your post needs improvement. You skirted the code requirement by formatting a URL as code.

Comment: "but the script has an error." OK so clearly show the error here OR better yet just create a Snippet right here in your question with the smallest set of code that reproduces your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error results from the fact that you call `popover` on Highcharts point object. You need to call the function on some HTML element, the closest one seems to be a data label.

```
    events: {
      click: function() {
        var popoverHtml = '...';

        $(this.dataLabel.div).popover({
          html: true,
          placement: 'top',
          content: popoverHtml,
          trigger: 'manual'
        }).popover('toggle');
      }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pyz46j51/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.networkgraph.dataLabels

Comment: Please don't encourage poor quality posts and rules avoidance by posting answers. Also, your demo could've just as easily been _here_.